# install play-framework in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, web-applications, playframework

I have copied zipped file from the playframework.org website and unzipped it at a location.
I have inserted it in my .bashrc profile to set up as PATH environment.

But still, the play command is not accessible from anywhere.

And even in the installed directory of the framework, the play file is not running as it is.

I have to prefix python before any play command to run it.

Am i making a mistake somewhere?

Please help me.

Comment: Got the answer!
move the unzipped play folder into opt dir by typing
"sudo mv play-1.0.1 /opt/play"
and then give another command
"source /etc/profile"

And now one can run play command from anywhere in the shell..

Mods!Please close this question.

Comment: Put your comment as an answer. If there's no other answer in 2 days it will convert in an accepted answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got the answer! 
Move the unzipped play folder into opt directory by typing

```
sudo mv play-1.0.1 /opt/play
```

and then give another command

```
source /etc/profile
```

And now one can run play command from anywhere in the shell..

Comment: This worked best for me:                                         `echo 'export PATH=/Applications/play-1.2.4:$PATH' >> ~/.profile`

Answer (score 20):

Suppose that the path of the play directory is `/home/yourName/play`

open the terminal and type the following

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/yourName/play
export PATH
```

then you will be able to access `play` command from anywhere

Answer (score 7):

Not to beat a dead horse but here's another way about it similar to the last post. Just ad an alias to your ~/.bashrc

```
alias play="/home/usrName/javaApi/play-1.1/play"
```

According to the .bashrc you could alternately add it to ~/.bash_aliases   which seems to be best practice according to the comments in the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
source ~/.bashrc #would have done the trick probably
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to tell the terminal that "play" is a bash script.  You will need to either rename play to play.sh, or run it with "bash play."  Additionally the script needs to have executable permissions.

I set it up with the following steps:

- *extract to* ~/opt/play-2.1-RC1
- mv ~/opt/play-2.1-RC1/play ~/opt/play-2.1-RC1/play.sh
- chmod +x ~/opt/play-2.1-RC1/play.sh
- alias play="/home/rob/opt/play-2.1-RC1/play.sh"

*Note that the alias can be run in a terminal, but to persist you will need to copy it to ~/.bashrc*

With this setup, local user can type play from any location.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

> echo 'export PATH=/Applications/play-1.2.4:$PATH' >> ~/.profile