# In which Ubuntu folder should the Play framework be unzipped?

Tags: java, ubuntu, playframework

In which Ubuntu folder should the Play framework be unzipped and why (play look like that include server)?

Comment: Also, check out this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491586/install-play-framework-in-ubuntu-9-10

Answer (score 1):

The user's home directory

```
/home/[username]/play
```

Check out the install guide for more details

> http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/install

Comment: this link say something opposite or i wrong? http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-play-framework

Comment: No, the link confirms what I've said - Really you could put it where ever you want as long as you define the path to Play in your bash profile. Common practice is to define it in your home path

Comment: ok, but play include server inside and he should not be installed in home directory, only the source code should be in home directory - please explain if I wrong, I have django background

Comment: I organize my development directory as follows: `/home/[user-name]/dev/[project]`. User permissions typically work out better by doing this.  Even if the code I'm using comes bundled with a server (Rails, Node), I still use this organizational structure. In production things are a bit different, but thats an issue for serverfault, not stackoverflow.